# Statistical Test for Employee Engagement Relative to Benchmark

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, survey

I have a set of employee engagement survey results scored on a Likert scale from one company. There approximately ten survey questions. Typically there are a few hundred responses per company.

I have the same survey results from a number of other companies (Approximately ten). For each question, I want to conduct a statistical test to determine whether employees are more of less engaged versus the benchmark. I am struggling with how to conduct this.

It seems like one approach would be to translate the Likert scale to numerical values. For example, perhaps `strongly agree =5, agree=4, neutral=3`, etc. Then I believe I could perform an unpaired t-test assuming unequal variance to test whether the mean engagement level is different than the mean engagement level for the benchmark group.

Second approach I think of would be to calculate a percentage favorable (defined as the percentage of people that selected strongly agree or agree) and perform a test for a difference in proportion. I understand that I could use a t-test here again.

Third approach would be the same as the second approach, but instead of running the test on the percentages,  I could translate the percentage favorable into count of favorable to create a 2x2 table of favorable vs not favorable and test company vs benchmark.Then I could use a Chi-squared table.

What is the recommended approach here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those are reasonable ideas (though I would scratch the second one because engagement proportions could be quite negatively biased, I would favor the chi square or Fisher's exact instead)

Comment: There probably are several useful approaches. But I would need more info to give a recommendation. Take Q1 for example. How many responses do you have from the 'benchmark' company With what are you comparing these Q1 responses? One other company (at a time) or Q1 scores from 'a number` of other companies merged together? How many other companies? How many questions on the questionnaire? // I suppose you know that if you do tests for 1000 comparisons at the 5% level, you will find 5%-significant differences in 50 comparisons, even if  no differences exist.

Comment: Thanks both! @BruceET, I have attempted to update my question to address your questions. This is very useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are fake data for Q1 for illustration at the benchmark company (200 responses) and at one of the other companies (352). The `p` vectors indicate proportions; R turns them into probabilities. The
other company is simulated to have more Likert `2`s and `3`'s
and fewer Likert `5`'s than the benchmark company.

```
set.seed(2019)
bnchmrk = sample(1:5, 200, rep=T, p=c(1,1,2,3,5))
co.nr.2 = sample(1:5, 352, rep=T, p=c(1,2,3,3,2))
DTA = rbind(tabulate(bnchmrk),tabulate(co.nr.2)); DTA
```

Here is a chi-squared table of counts for various Likert categories:

```
DTA
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   13   30   47   95   # benchmark
[2,]   28   60  101  100   63   # other co
```

**Chi-squared test of homogeneity.** The `chisq.test` procedure shows a highly significant
difference in the pattern of Likert responses:

```
chi.out = chisq.test(DTA); chi.out

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 61.034, df = 4, p-value = 1.759e-12
```

A matrix of observed counts is retrieved usind `$`-notation to check against the original data. A matrix of expected counts shows that they are all greater than 5.

```
chi.out$obs
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   15   13   30   47   95
[2,]   28   60  101  100   63
chi.out$exp
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
 [1,] 15.57971 26.44928 47.46377 53.26087  57.24638
 [2,] 27.42029 46.55072 83.53623 93.73913 100.75362
```

Because there are significant differences, Pearson
residuals with large absolute values point the way to
the largest discrepancies between observed and expected counts. Differences in Likert scores 2, 3, and 5 seem
worth examining.

```
chi.out$res
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -0.1468694 -2.615122 -2.534877 -0.8578879  4.989817
[2,]  0.1107069  1.971223  1.910735  0.6466573 -3.761216
```

**Two-sample tests.** A Welch two sample t test and a nonparametric 2-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test both show
highly significant differences between the two companies.

The t test makes sense only if you are willing to view Likert scores as numerical data
for which averages make sense. The accompanying one-sided CI shows that Likert scores at the benchmark company average about half a point higher.

I did one-sided tests,
which would be appropriate if you hypothesized before
seeing the data that the benchmark company would have
higher Likert scores.

```
t.test(bnchmrk, co.nr.2, alt="gr")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  bnchmrk and co.nr.2
t = 6.0534, df = 394.07, p-value = 1.653e-09
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4784205       Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   3.9700    3.3125 

wilcox.test(bnchmrk, co.nr.2, alt="gr") 

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
     with continuity correction

data:  bnchmrk and co.nr.2
W = 46800, p-value = 1.605e-11
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is greater than 0
```

On request (with parameter `conf.int=T`) the Wilcoxon test also provides a confidence interval (not shown here).